# How to compare the values of a column separated by /

Tags: text-processing, awk

I want to compare values of the same column separated by `/`

```
session-manager-0    3/5    1 >>> want to compare second column value 3 and 5 using awk.
session-manager-1    5/5    1
session-manager-2    5/5    1
```

Comment: Kindly post excepted output

Comment: There is a way to do using just `awk`, but I think I would just pipe the numeric values using `sed` to `awk`. E.g., `sed 's@^.*\([0-9]\+\)\/\([0-9]\+\).*$@\1 \2@' file`. With this you can  extract the columns using awk

Comment: @GiuseppeClemente you never need sed when you're using awk.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `split` to subdivide a field based on a second delimiter, ex.

```
$ awk 'split($2,a,"/") > 1 && a[2] > a[1]+0' file
session-manager-0    3/5    1 >>> want to compare second column value 3 and 5 using awk.
```

- if `split` generates at least 2 values; and
- the second split value is greater than the first (after forcing numeric comparison)
- then apply the default `print` rule

Comment: @EdMorton sure - but no harm in having some basic input validation imho

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk -F'[[:space:]/]+' '$2 < $3' file
session-manager-0    3/5    1 >>> want to compare second column value 3 and 5 using awk.
```

Comment: Smart solution, I like it! I hadn't thought to modify the field separator. I think your should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk` only, you need to manage multiple matches (somewhat similar to what you can find in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1116193/awk-extract-multiple-groups-from-each-line)).

This is my pure-`awk` solution:

```
awk '{
  match($0, /[0-9]+\/[0-9]+/);                      # match number/number pattern
  pattern=substr($0,RSTART, RLENGTH);               # store match in $pattern
  match(pattern, /[0-9]+/);                         # match first number
  num1=substr(pattern,RSTART,RLENGTH);              # store it in $num1
  sub(/[0-9]+\//,"",pattern);                       # remove 'number/' from $pattern
  match(pattern, /[0-9]+/);                         # match second number
  num2=substr(pattern,RSTART,RLENGTH);              # store it in $num2
  if ($num1 > $num2){ print num1, ">", num2 }       # do your comparisons
  else if ($num1 < $num2) { print num1, "<", num2 } # as you please
  else { print num1, "=", num2  }                   # (this is just an example)
  }' file
```

---

**However**, in this situation I would actually use `sed` for extract the two numeric values and then pipe the output to `awk`. The following command does the same of the above, but I think it is functionally cleaner:

```
sed 's@^.*\([0-9]\+\)\/\([0-9]\+\).*$@\1 \2@' file |
  awk '{if ($1 > $2){ print $1, ">", $2 }
        else if ($1 < $2) { print $1, "<", $2 }
        else { print $1, "=", $2  }}'
```